# Stack Exchange Vote Counter

Tags: code-golf, quine, internet, stack-exchange-api

Write a program/function that returns the vote count of its own Stack Exchange answer at the time of its execution.

- Your program/function may access this page ([codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82609](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82609)) off the internet, however:
- Your program/function may not accept any user input and
- The use of URL shorteners is not allowed
- Your program/function may use only its own source as a reference point to its vote count (for example: no referencing strings of text in its contained answer but not in its own source)
- Your program/function must output its own vote count and **only** its own vote count (for example: no returning all vote counts on this page)

This is code-golf, shortest code wins.

Comment: ``perl -e'($_)=`curl -s http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/123?site=codegolf`;/score":(\d+)/&&print$1'`` looks like it should work, but doesn't. But maybe someone can use that.

Comment: To everyone else who's trying and failing to use the API: It serves the response gzip encoded, even if the client does not support it.

Comment: "Your program/function may use only its own source as a reference point to its vote count" Is a bit confusing. Does this mean that answers should try to identify themselves only using knowledge of their own code, and not through something like a post id? I don't think that such a rule would be good, as it can be broken by anyone else posting a new answer.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I did put a bit of thought into breaking other peoples answers, and I even considered making this a KOTH where your source tries to undermine another answer, although in the end that seemed to be pushing the format more than I wanted... I added the `using its own source` bit to prevent users from setting up the page to make it easier to find itself without contributing to its byte count, in the case that the answer doesn't use the post id method.

Comment: Alright, the wording is a bit weird. I would recommend instead of allowing certain behaviour in this way, instead directly ban using any web services besides those supplied by stackexchange (unless I've misunderstood you). As a side note, due to the nature of the completeness problem, it is not possible to make something like this unbreakable. The best you can do is make it implausible to be broken.

Comment: I don't get it. The question states to only use the page contents at `codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82609` as a reference. Yet everyone appears to be using the api at `api.stackexchange.com`. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer? (I want the badge about 2x outvoting the accepted answer, which is Dennis's convex one)

Comment: @Dendrobium: I had developed an noncompeting answer that was a cousin to your KOTH idea, and I can't recommend going that route.  Mine flopped miserably and was mod deleted for this and other reasons (as it should have been).  Rather than undermining an answer, it went the other way and was self-deprecating while it complimented whichever author and answer was currently in the lead.  This still had potential to influence votes and cause confusion if anyone had taken it seriously.

Comment: Please accept an answer. It has been quite a while.

Comment: Bash, 5 bytes ‘echo 0’

Answer (score 47):

## jQuery + JavaScript, 85 bytes

```js
$.get("//api.stackexchange.com/posts/82610?site=codegolf",d=>alert(d.items[0].score))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### History

- -6 bytes because I was using the var `data` instead of `d`.
- -3 bytes thanks to @msh210
- -13 bytes thanks to @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ
- -4 bytes thanks to @user6188402
- -5 bytes thanks to @Suever
- -4 bytes thanks to @RobW

#### Recommended usage

- Run snippet.
- Upvote.
- Run snippet, and be amazed as the number magically increases.

#### Bonus!!

Who doesn't like a bonus?

```js
$.getJSON("//api.stackexchange.com/posts/" + prompt() + "?site=codegolf",d=>alert(d.items[0].score));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Enter the ID into the bonus and it will tell you the score.

<s>Even more bonus!! Run this snippet to *automatically* run the program, upvote, and run again! (Requires rep > 15, auth). If it doesn't work, please tell me.</s>

Comment: `posts` instead of `answers` and `http` instead of `https` saves three bytes (or perhaps you can omit `http:` altogether?). (Untested.)

Comment: Also, try `d=>alert(d.items[0].score)`

Comment: You can use `http://` and it will 301 redirect to `https://` Better yet, just remove the http altogether `//api.stackexchange.com...`

Comment: jQuery is not a language, neither an inbuilt library in JS. So if you are using that, include the byte count of jQuery in your score too.

Comment: @Optimizer: This is the proper way to do it: consider JS + jQuery to effectively be its own "language". See this meta post: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9279/12914

Comment: @El'endiaStarman I don't really see a conclusion to that. It need more answers or more discussion on the existing answer to really call it "proper way"

Comment: Use `$.get` instead of `$.getJSON`. The API's content type is `application/json`, and jQuery will automatically treat the response as JSON.

Comment: Doesn't work if you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: I got: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 18,
  "colno": 74
} working with chrome

Comment: Doesn't this answer violate the very first rule of the question?

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery.

Comment: @programmer5000 Did you really downvote? Vote as you see fit, but this is 100% jQuery. `$` is an alias of `jQuery`, and the main body of my post is a call to `$.post`.

Answer (score 24):

## JavaScript ES6, 107 bytes

```js
fetch`//api.stackexchange.com/posts/82672?site=codegolf`.then(r=>r.json()).then(b=>alert(b.items[0].score))
```

Real programmers don't use `XMLHttpRequest`. Real programmers use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Well... you got me there. I never knew about this API!

Comment: I'm getting an error that `fetch` isn't defined

Comment: @PythonMaster The Fetch API is not yet available in all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

Answer (score 21):

## Bash, <s>80</s> <s>79</s> <s>75</s> 69 bytes

```
w3m api.stackexchange.com/posts/82616?site=codegolf|tr ,: \\t|cut -f20
```

For scoring purposes, `\t` should be replaced with a TAB character.

This requires `w3m`, which should be available by default on most Linux distros.

*Thanks to @NoOneIsHere for -2 bytes!*

#### How it works

`w3m` is a command-line web browser. It queries the URL and (normally) displays its content in a readable format. Here, we just (ab)use it to avoid the call to `zcat` that `curl` would require, since SE serves the API response gzip-compressed.

`tr ,: \^I` replaces all commas and colons with tabs, which are `cut`'s default field delimiter.

Finally, `cut -f20` removes everything but the twentieth field, which is the vote count.

Comment: Or `--compressed`, which is even longer than `zcat`.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>175</s> <s>165</s> <s>160</s> 145 bytes

Saved lotsa bytes thanks to Optimizer and Dendrobium! They're all multiples of five!

Using plain ol' javascript. Who needs those newfangled libraries? [Real programmers](https://xkcd.com/378/) use `XMLHttpRequest()`

```
with(new XMLHttpRequest)send(open("get","//api.stackexchange.com/posts/82614?site=codegolf"),onload=_=>alert(response.match(/re..([0-9]+)/)[1]))
```

### Test it out

```js
alert=x=>o.innerHTML=x;

with(new XMLHttpRequest)send(open("get","//api.stackexchange.com/posts/82614?site=codegolf"),onload=_=>alert(response.match(/re..([0-9]+)/)[1]))
```

```css
*{font-family:Consolas,monospace;}
```

```html
<div id=o></div>
```

Comment: @Optimizer Thanks! But why use `prompt`?

Comment: @Optimizer For some reason, `"g"` doesn't work as an option for me.

Comment: `with(new XMLHttpRequest)(open("get","//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/82614?site=codegolf"),onload=_=>alert(response.items[0].score),send(responseType="json"))` for -5 bytes

Comment: @Dendrobium Oh, nice one. I forgot about `with`

Comment: @Optimizer I get `TypeError: response.split(...)[12] is undefined",`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Expanding on @Optimizer's suggestion, `with(new XMLHttpRequest){open("get","//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/82614?site=codegolf");send(onload=_=>alert(response.split\`:\`[12].split\`,\`[0]))}` for -10 bytes

Comment: `with(new XMLHttpRequest)send(open("get","//api.stackexchange.com/posts/82614?site=codegolf"),onload=_=>alert(response.match(/re..([0-9])/)[1]))` for 143 bytes

Comment: `with(new XMLHttpRequest)send(open("get","//api.stackexchange.com/posts/82614?site=codegolf"),onload=_=>alert(response.match(/\d+/g)[25]))` 137

Comment: You can shave off some bytes by using synchronous XMLHttpRequest. The regexp can be shortened using `exec` instead of `match` and a look-ahead (so that the result is an array of size 1, so you don't need `[1]`. This works as long as you don't change your display name to end with a digit: `with(new XMLHttpRequest)send(open("get","//api.stackexchange.com/posts/82614?site=codegolf",0)),alert(/\d+(?=,"l)/.exec(response))` 130

Answer (score 7):

## [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)+[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 69 bytes

```
w3m api.stackexchange.com/posts/82615?site=codegolf|jq .items[].score
```

I used `curl` and `zcat` before; `w3m` is inspired by Dennis’s (strikingly similar) answer. It turns out `jq` and `tr`/`cut` have the same byte cost!

Answer (score 6):

## [Convex](http://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex) 0.5, 63 bytes

```
0000000: 22 d1 2e 46 91 32 e5 69 5d b2 66 81 12 a4 8d d1  "..F.2.i].f.....
0000010: 27 40 b5 32 47 68 97 2c b9 5c 22 05 16 49 10 31  '@.2Gh.,.\"..I.1
0000020: 44 9e f3 0a 6a 16 b0 68 91 93 35 0b 96 dc 91 0a  D...j..h..5.....
0000030: 3c 18 80 22 dc 67 27 3c 2f 32 36 39 3d 37 3e     <..".g'</269=7>
```

This retrieves the score from the search page instead of the API, specifically from the query https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion:82714. Fortunately, `inquestion` also works for answers.

#### Verification

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US
$ cat gen.convex
"codegolf.stackexchange.com:80/search?q=inquestion:82714"Ö`"Üg'</269=7>"
$ java -jar Convex/out/builds/convex-0.5/convex/convex.jar gen.conv > count.conv
$ cksum count.conv
2414634109 63 count.conv
$ java -jar Convex/out/builds/convex-0.5/convex/convex.jar count.conv
1
```

#### How it works

```
"..."Ü           e# Use the built-in string compression to push
                 e# "codegolf.stackexchange.com:80/search?q=inquestion:82714".
      g          e# Retrieve the HTML page at that URL.
       '</       e# Split at occurrences of '<'.
          269=   e# Select the chunk at index 269.
                 e# This pushes "strong>", followed by the vote count.
              7> e# Discard the leading seven characters.
```

Comment: This is amazing. How did you even know that this language can do this?

Comment: It's a CJam fork. I originally wrote my answer in CJam (67 bytes), but then I remembered that Convex has built-in string compression.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>89</s> <s>87</s> 81 bytes

Thanks Python...

```
•1Ö8•D’£Ø ˆå§¾.‡¢ as g;#.¾¿„–(g.ˆåƒÛ('·Ç://ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/…é/ÿ/').‚Ø())’.er¡14èžz£þ
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, 103 bytes

```
g=@getfield;g(g(webread('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/82611?site=codegolf'),'items'),'score')
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (Node.js), 166 Bytes

-1 byte because @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ taught me how to count ;)

-4 bytes thanks to @NoOneIsHere

```
require("http").get("http://api.stackexchange.com/posts/82620?site=codegolf",a=>a.on("data",d=>console.log(JSON.parse(require("zlib").gunzipSync(d)).items[0].score)))
```

This is somewhat embarrassing. Dang you SE for gzipping your API! /s

Any improvements are very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>128</s> 107 bytes

```
using Requests
f()=split(readall(get("http://api.stackexchange.com/posts/82621?site=codegolf")),r":|,")[20]
```

This is a function that takes no input and returns the score of this post as a string. It requires the `Requests` package to be installed.

How it works:

- `get` makes a GET request to the SE API
- `readall` reads the raw bytes in the response and returns a string
- `split` splits the string at colons and commas
- The 20th element of the resulting array is the score of the post

Saved 21 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (Node.js + [Unirest](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html)), 123 bytes

```
require("unirest").get("http://api.stackexchange.com/posts/82683?site=codegolf").end(x=>console.log(x.body.items[0].score))
```

I like this library, because it automatically parses JSON.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 137 bytes

Pretty straight forward. The uncompressing takes a lot of bytes:

```
<?=json_decode(gzinflate(substr(file_get_contents('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/82619?site=codegolf'),10)),1)[items][0][score];
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```
print
  json_decode(
    gzinflate(
      substr(
        file_get_contents('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/82619?site=codegolf'),
        10
      )
    ),
    1
  )
  [items][0][score];
```

Comment: Note that `join(file(` can be used to shorten `file_get_contents(` ;)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 121 bytes

Without api.

```
<?php preg_match('/t ">(.*)/',file_get_contents('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/82799/ajax-load'),$v);echo$v[1];
```

Gets the whole post and extracts the vote counts with regex. (don't parse HTML with regex!)

Ungolfed:

```
<?php
   preg_match('/t ">(.*)/',
              file_get_contents('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/82799/ajax-load'),
              $v);

   echo $v[1];
```

Comment: Can you remove `http:`?

Comment: @NoOne No, doesn't appear to work then.

Comment: Note that `join(file(` can be used to shorten `file_get_contents(` ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 45 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•2íÐ•’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/„¤/ÿ?€¼=ƒËŠˆ’žYì.w'ŒÂ¡θ',¡нþ
```

No TIO for the entire program, because the `.w` builtin to access the internet doesn't work on TIO.

**Explanation:**

We start by creating the url, and accessing it:

```python
•2íÐ•       # Push compressed integer 190437 (the id of this answer)
  ’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/„¤/ÿ?€¼=ƒËŠˆ’
            # Push dictionary string "api.stackexchange.com/posts/ÿ?site=codegolf",
            # where the `ÿ` is automatically filled with the 190437
    žY      # Push builtin "https://"
      ì     # And prepend it in front of the string
.w          # Go to this website, and get all its contents
```

[Try it online (without the `.w`).](https://tio.run/##AUwAs/9vc2FiaWX//@KAojLDrcOQ4oCi4oCZwrjCuC7DguKAmuKAucK6LsWSxZIv4oCewqQvw78/4oKswrw9xpLDi8Wgy4bigJnFvlnDrP//)

After that, we extract the score from the JSON:

```python
'ŒÂ        '# Push dictionary string "score"
   ¡        # Split the website content on this
    θ       # Only leave the last item (of the two)
     ',¡   '# Split this string on ","
        н   # And this time leave the first item (i.e. `":10`)
         þ  # Only leave the digits of this string
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVC7TsNAEPwVtAU0Jn6FQCxFFJQICYkSIWs5r51N7Dtzd06IojR8An/AX9BAQUSL@KNwNgmioKGc3ZnZ2VEGb5k2m4P3x/XD29PH84H39vT5sn7dbJbAlioDyfUS1FyShmQJmurGomUlITkKgpPAg8aQTjlzOIrCHbaLmiBx9IKNJU0ZeIBCUG1TjdathgMPaq1yLinlCouWPba2Nonvc89YFNMeV0Wje0JV/gXlV5e9SV2cmlEYnewXo9AZZmzqEhepxKqVn9OM5d6ZbnhiDElHKFlOf/kKlVGhyvzbnu7FGGVB3YE2tPG7D/xp63MofnxWHhihtDvhvivR2BSF5RnbRZp1v4RHg0EcRnHY90Bo6ur5Y1UrJ90Wg9LMXaPbYdteOAz68fF/MqP/rYHVjQdjNGnVhcyxNOTBXaMsphXeQxIHwQ5rqpAlywKSaNhffQE)

An equal 10-[bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative for this second part could be:

```python
„ŒÂ‚¡       # Push dictionary string "score after"
     #      # Split it on spaces: ["score","after"]
      ¡     # Split the website content on these
       Ås   # Only leave the middle element
         þ  # Only leave the digits of this string
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVDLSgNBEPwVacHTmn0kRrMgHjyKIHgUWdrZzqbN7sw6PauGEBDBH/DoQfBHPCT4I/5InF0fePDisbqrqqvLCF4wrdfvd89vj6v797un5cvm8mX1IKvX9XoO7KgSSM/mYG40WUjnYKluHDo2GtKdKNqLAmiEbMa5x0kSf2M3qwlSTy9YHFnKIQBUimqXWXR@NRoGUFsz5pIyrrBo2RPnaknDkHviUE17XBWN7SlThcc0Pj3pXdbFgezHyd5WsR97w5ylLnGWaaxa@RFds944tA1fipD2hJL19JevMjkVphx/2tOtmqAuqDvQhpaw@yCctj7b6sdnEYAoY/0J/12J4jJUjq/ZzbK8@yXeGQ77cdKPBwEoS109f6xq46VfxaCWG9/o17BtLx5Fg/7ufzJj@KmBxXkAE5Ss6kKOsRQK4KoxDrMKbyHtR9E3tlQha9YFpMlosPgA)

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•2íÐ•` is `190437`, `’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/„¤/ÿ?€¼=ƒËŠˆ’` is `"api.stackexchange.com/posts/ÿ?site=codegolf"`, `'ŒÂ` is `"score"`, and `„ŒÂ‚¡` is `"score after"`.

PS/EDIT: I realize that by using the `þ` I assume I will never get a negative score. ;)

Comment: [-3 without `žYì`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224104/94066).

Comment: @Makonede I'm using `https` instead of `http` here. Nice tip regardless, though. I will definitely keep this in mind, and it might potentially golf some of my other answers.

Comment: `http` should work just fine though, no?

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 87 bytes

```
=Mid(Index(ImportData("http://api.stackexchange.com/posts/203609?site=codegolf"),7),7,9
```

Sheets will add the trailing parentheses automatically.

`ImportData` will treat the result as a CSV and split the text into columns.
`Index(~,10)` pulls the 10th entry from that split result.
`Mid(~,12,99)` starts at the 7th character and pulls up to the next 9.

So long as the score doesn't get to 10^9, this will work fine.

Here's a screenshot showing the three steps:

[image: Screenshot]